# Rails timestamp validation avoid null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I am creating a REST API in rails only the update though. What I want to do is be able to pass in a timestamp and update the record with the result.

I am simply making use of

```
@my_class = MyClass.find(params[:id])

@my_class.update_attributes!(params)
```

and this works fine for this as expected but when a value is passed in say `'2013-07-08 20:00'` I would like to throw a bad request as I only want dates in format `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'`

The current default behavior is to just quietly set the field to null.
Whats the best to get this to throw an error instead?
I have tried doing a `validate_format_of` but since it gets set to null it just validates the null and not the value being handed in.

Obviously I can just check the parameter but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Did my respond help you with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure both allow_blank and allow_nil are false?

```
validates_format_of :my_time_stamp, with: /[0-9]{1,4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}/, :allow_nil => false, :allow_blank => false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Time#parse` is a better solution than a regex match.  This returns a Time object when the string can be parsed successfully:

```
>> Time.parse("'2013-07-08 20:00'")
=> 2013-07-08 20:00:00 -0400
```

When the string cannot be parsed, it raises an error:

```
>> Time.parse("meow")
ArgumentError: no time information in "meow"
```

This does not meet your specifications exactly because certain fields are not required.  For example, this does not raise an error.

```
>> Time.parse('2013-07-08')
=> 2013-07-08 00:00:00 -0400
```

Parsing the time and formatting the output should meet your requirements.  This will correctly evaluate to false when the hh:mm:ss is not provided:

```
>> str = '2013-07-08'
=> "2013-07-08"
>> Time.parse(str).to_formatted_s(:db) == str
=> false
```

When the hh:mm:ss is provided, it will evaluate to true:

```
>> str = '2013-07-08 20:00:45'
=> "2013-07-08 20:00:45"
>> Time.parse(str).to_formatted_s(:db) == str
=> true
```